# echo next upcoming _start based on date

Tags: php, mysql

Okay; What I'm trying to do is use the `$currentdate` variable to select from the table `usr_timetable_entrys` the next upcoming `_start` column where the `username` = `'$username'`

```
$currentdate = time();
```

I use the following query to get all the upcoming times from the table in the picture.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usr_timetable_entrys` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```

Below is a picture of the table structure;

[image]

**Desired Result:**

So for example using the values in the table above if the day of the week was  Tuesday the next upcoming `_start` would be `wednesday_start` which would be at `05:00:00`.

Another example would be if the day of the week was a Saturday the next upcoming `_start` would be `monday_start` at `00:00:00`.

How can I use PHP to select the next upcoming `_start` on a weekly basis.

I know this question is pretty messy and I am expecting down votes I tried to explain the problem I'm having as best as I can so I'm really sorry If you don't understand. Thankyou for any help and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select case

```
 select 
   case 
      DAYOFWEEK('$currentdate') 
        when 1 then sunday_start
        when 2 then monday_start
         .....
        when 7 then saturday_start
  end
from `usr_timetable_entrys` 
WHERE `username` = '$username'";



$sql = "SELECT  
          `username`, 
           CASE 
              DAYOFWEEK('$currentdate') 
                WHEN 1 THEN sunday_start
                WHEN 2 THEN monday_start
                WHEN 3 THEN tuesday_start
                WHEN 4 THEN wednesday_start
                WHEN 5 THEN thursday_start
                WHEN 6 THEN friday_start                
                WHEN 7 THEN saturday_start
          END as day_start
      FROM `usr_timetable_entrys` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can implement this into what I'm trying to achieve. :(

Comment: This probably wont work. it looks like `sunday_start` etc are `var_char` columns. notice the `"N/A"` on `tuesday_start` ?

Comment: @andrew    the query return the content of the column  (date or string) .. could be the OP must convert  $currentdate for a proper date behavior